# Layout is not showing any elements into the activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview

I try many time to find the bugs, why is not shown into the layout.

the bugs is after I run my application is not showing any elements into the activity.

[image]

This is the XML Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.ammarfalmban.carbs.BeansDetailsActivity">

            <ImageView
                android:paddingTop="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/beans_food_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity_beans_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Song"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="209dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="جرام كربوهيدرات"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                tools:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/beans_food_carb_text_view"
                android:layout_width="209dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                tools:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="201dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="209dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="سعرة حرارية"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    tools:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/beans_food_calories_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="209dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    tools:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="201dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

This is the Java Code

```
        package com.example.ammarfalmban.carbs;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class BeansDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_beans_details);
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String beans_quantity = intent.getStringExtra("beans_quantity");
                String beans_carbs = intent.getStringExtra("beans_carbs");

         String beans_calories = intent.getStringExtra("beans_calories");

         TextView songNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.quantity_beans_text_view);
                songNameTextView.setText(beans_quantity);

         TextView artistNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.beans_food_calories_text_view);

                artistNameTextView.setText(beans_calories); TextView carbsTextView = findViewById(R.id.beans_food_carb_text_view);
                carbsTextView.setText(beans_carbs);
    }
    }
```

Comment: `tools:...` is a tag for the preview in your IDE like Android Studio. The tag and its attributes is ignored when the program is running. Also your Textview-names point to a song-program, while you show calories in it. This can become quite confusing, so it might help you to clean your code a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change this

```
 tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
```

you should replace `tools` to `android` in your views

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in xml file in background tag attribute change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:paddingTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/beans_food_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_beans_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="Song"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="جرام كربوهيدرات"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beans_food_carb_text_view"
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="201dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="سعرة حرارية"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beans_food_calories_text_view"
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="201dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```